# How can a warrior take an enemy city?

Tags: freeciv

I have a warrior standing next to a young small enemy city.  How can I attack it?  I do not see any options to attack.

Comment: Have you ever attacked before successfully, or is this question basically "How do I order a unit to attack?"?

Answer (score 4):

Ok this is lame. But I am new to the game and the wiki does not state the obvious.

You must *declare war*  against in order to have the option to attack.

Answer (score 3):

To attack a city (or any other unit) just move the unit to the field of the unit or city. If the enemy's city is empty, a combat unit will take over control of the city. There is a [wiki entry about combat](http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Combat) digging a little deeper into the topic..